# Unable to drag and drop sometimes

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, awt

```
package newjframe;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;


public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {



public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public class Draggable extends JComponent {

    private Point pointPressed;
    private JComponent draggable;

    public Draggable(final JComponent component, final int x, final int y) {
        draggable = component;
        setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        setLocation(x, y);
        setSize(component.getPreferredSize());
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(component);
        MouseInputAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseHandler();
        addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);
        addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
    }

    public class MouseHandler extends MouseInputAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(final MouseEvent e) {
            Point pointDragged = e.getPoint();
            Point location = getLocation();
            location.translate(pointDragged.x - pointPressed.x,
                    pointDragged.y - pointPressed.y);
            setLocation(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
            pointPressed = e.getPoint();
        }
    }
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    layer = new javax.swing.JLayeredPane();
    cbb = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    label = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    cbb.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"}));
    cbb.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cbbActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    layer.setLayer(cbb, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    layer.setLayer(label, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layerLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(layer);
    layer.setLayout(layerLayout);
    layerLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layerLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(41, 41, 41)
            .addComponent(cbb, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(129, 129, 129)
            .addComponent(label)
            .addContainerGap(202, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layerLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        layerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layerLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
            .addGroup(layerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(label)
                .addComponent(cbb, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(329, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout panelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel);
    panel.setLayout(panelLayout);
    panelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(layer)
    );
    panelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(layer)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void cbbActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int[] xy = {100, 200, 300};
    label.setText("DRAG THIS");
    switch (cbb.getSelectedIndex()) {
        case 0:
            draglabel = new Draggable(label, xy[0], xy[0]);
            layer.add(draglabel);
            break;
        case 1:
            draglabel = new Draggable(label, xy[0], xy[1]);
            layer.add(draglabel);
            break;
        case 2:
            draglabel = new Draggable(label, xy[0], xy[2]);
            layer.add(draglabel);
            break;
        default:
            draglabel = new Draggable(label, xy[0], xy[0]);
            layer.add(draglabel);
    }
}                                   


public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> cbb;
private javax.swing.JLabel label;
private javax.swing.JLayeredPane layer;
private javax.swing.JPanel panel;
// End of variables declaration                   
Draggable draglabel;
}
```

The above code should allow the Jlabels to be dragged and dropped with ease, but every time they're called with the actionlistener in JComboBox, they become harder to drag and drop. GIF added to for better clarity https://imgur.com/rPL5ZMC I have tried repaint() method in the class method, and actionlistner but it didn't work

Comment: Have you been able to confirm whether your mouse listener is being called at the correct time?

Comment: yes, they're called at the correct time. I've tried repaint() too but it doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure about others, but since you're asking for help with misbehaving code, I for one would be able to more fully and quickly understand your problem if you would create and post a viable [mcve] with your question.

Comment: Are you trying to drag Draggable? Probably better to have the parent container handle the dragging

Comment: I do see that each time the actionPerformed method is called, 6 more `Draggable` objects are created. Not sure if previously created objects have been removed or not, or if they could be "gumming the works".

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think the previously created objects may have been the cause. I've tried to remove by giving null values for x and y, but couldn't remove.

Comment: You're confusing variables with objects. Setting a variable to `null` has no effect on the underlying object, and usually will not "remove" an object especially if it is displayed in a GUI. But again we're just guessing here, and without a [mcve] I fear we'll continue to guess.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've edit the post for you

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i've tried setting the objects = null and recreating the objects but the problem persists.

Comment: What happens if you start your `actionPerformed(...)` with this: `if (draglabel != null) {
            remove(draglabel);
        }` and finish it with `revalidate(); repaint();`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It's the same

Comment: @BongMeister: what is the point of the code? what are you trying to do with it? Note also that your demo code does not reproduce your issue for me

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm just trying everything to remove the "lag" from the program. like what this gif is showing https://imgur.com/rPL5ZMC

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i realise im creating new objects of the same name every time i'm calling the actionperformed method, i'm trying to delete the old object every time before calling them again.

Comment: No, I'm not asking what your problem is -- you've established already that there is some lag in dragging on repeated selections from the comb box. I have 2 unaddressed questions: 1) what is the *overall* purpose of this part of your program? What are you trying to do here, what experience are you trying to give the user? How does the combo box figure in? and 2) your posted code does not reproduce your problem for me, and so I cannot make any recommendations yet.

Comment: Side issue: the container that you're dragging components in uses FlowLayout meaning that any dragging risks not remaining stable.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the misunderstanding. I'm creating a movie poster generator. To answer your question 1)In the combobox, there are some templates, pre-placed jlabels for the title, director, and actors/actresses. User can choose the template that they want and make modification to them (thus the drag and drop). 2)I've just realised that, I'm making some changes to the code.

Comment: For something like this, when you're not dragging from one program to another, I'd make things much simpler -- why not simply use a MouseListener and drag components with the listener. Using D&D unnecessarily just adds unnecessary complexity. But yes, by all means,please update the code with one that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've updated the post, this should exhibit the problem i'm trying to solve.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  Any suggestions?

Comment: Looking at it. For one, I still see you're missing the removal of the old dragged components as well as unnecessary complexity in that you're adding a JLabel to a JComponent for unknown reason. The Draggable shouldn't extend JComponent but rather should simply hold the JLabel and set its state. Looking some more.

Comment: And the JLayeredPane should **not** be using a GroupLayout or any other layout....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, I would tend to simplify try to clarify things, including:

- Use the much simpler MouseListener/MouseAdapter and not D&D as you initially were doing. You appear to have made this change.
- Not wrapping the JLabel unnecessarily in another component
- Thus the Mouse listeners would be added *directly* on the JLabel and not on a wrapper object.
- Not changing the JLayeredPane's default and unique layout
- Explicitly removing the old components before adding new ones
- Calling `repaint()` on the JLayeredPane after adding or removing components.

For example, something like this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;    
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestDragging extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] ITEMS = {"Item One", "Item Two", "Item Three"};
    private static final Dimension PREF_SIZE = new Dimension(400, 400);
    private JLabel label;
    private JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(ITEMS);
    private JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();

    public TestDragging() {
        comboBox.addActionListener(new ComboListener());
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(comboBox);

        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(PREF_SIZE);
        layeredPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(layeredPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private class ComboListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (label != null) {
                layeredPane.remove(label);
            }

            int index = comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
            int x = 100;
            int y = 100 + 100 * index;
            String text = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
            label = createDraggingLabel(x, y, text);

            layeredPane.add(label, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
            layeredPane.repaint();
        }

        private JLabel createDraggingLabel(int x, int y, String text) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
            label.setSize(label.getPreferredSize());
            label.setLocation(x, y);

            MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
            label.addMouseListener(myMouse);
            label.addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
            return label;
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TestDragging mainPanel = new TestDragging();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Dragging");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
    private Point pointPressed = null;

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        pointPressed = e.getPoint();
    } 

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();
        label.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        Point pointDragged = e.getPoint();
        Point location = label.getLocation();
        int dx = pointDragged.x - pointPressed.x;
        int dy = pointDragged.y - pointPressed.y;
        location.translate(dx, dy);
        label.setLocation(location);
        Container container = label.getParent();
        container.repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've called and instantiated the drag n drop function in the constructor then I've used label.setLocation(x, y) to solve this problem since the JComboBox merely determines the position of the labels, I do not need to have re-instantiate the object every time actionperformed is called.

Comment: This is off the wall, and is changing requirements that we have no knowledge of the whys of. Frustrating for me to be sure for I've wasted a lot of time over this, time I can never get back. Please remember that we're volunteers, and let's avoid this sort of futile exercise in the future.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I wasn't being clear and specific enough. I did redo some of the functions to get the desired output. I wouldn't say your time is wasted, I've learned something new from you today. I'll keep in mind and avoid this in the future. Thanks you very much.